# How to install apktool (jar file problem)?

Tags: apktool

I am trying to install the apktool. I am using [this link](https://bitbucket.org/iBotPeaches/apktool/downloads/). The link instructs to download the jar file and batch file and store it in the C:\Windows directory.

Batch file has following contents:

```
 @echo off
if "%PATH_BASE%" == "" set PATH_BASE=%PATH%
set PATH=%CD%;%PATH_BASE%;
chcp 65001 2>nul >nul
java -jar -Duser.language=en -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 "%~dp0\apktool.jar" %*
```

When I am executing batch file apktool.bat  from command line, I am getting following error:

> Error: Unable to access jarfile C:\Windows\apktool.jar

I have Windows 10 Pro installed on my system. I have i7 machine. I have provided the path of "C:\Windows" directory in PATH system variable.

Comment: (Please mind IP rights when reverse engineering.)

Comment: Right now I am following a tutorial but I don't know about IP rights.

Answer (score 1):

I am able to solve this problem. I downloaded the file apktool_2.3.4.jar. So I renamed it as apktool.jar and it solved my problem.

> > apktool Apktool v2.3.4 - a tool for reengineering Android apk files with smali v2.2.2 and baksmali v2.2.2 Copyright 2014 Ryszard
> >     Wiśniewski  Updated by Connor Tumbleson
>
> usage: apktool  -advance,--advanced   prints advance information. 
>   -version,--version    prints the version then exits usage: apktool if|install-framework [options]   -p,--frame-path  
>   Stores framework files into .  -t,--tag           Tag
>   frameworks using . usage: apktool d[ecode] [options]  
>   -f,--force              Force delete destination directory.  -o,--output        The name of folder that gets written. Default is apk.out  -p,--frame-path    Uses framework files located in
>   .  -r,--no-res             Do not decode resources.  -s,--no-src 
>   Do not decode sources.  -t,--frame-tag     Uses framework files
>   tagged by . usage: apktool b[uild] [options]  
>   -f,--force-all          Skip changes detection and build all files.  -o,--output        The name of apk that gets written. Default is dist/name.apk  -p,--frame-path    Uses framework files located in
>   .
>
> For additional info, see: http://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/ For
>   smali/baksmali info, see: https://github.com/JesusFreke/smali
>
> C:\Windows>

Answer (score 1):

> Rename your file to apktool.jar

*it should not be like this: apktool_2.4.0.jar*